# Derivative of $\cot x$ leading to an interesting result.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

When people first tend to find the derivative of $\cot x$ they rewrite as $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ and then find its derivative using the quotient rule. However, expressing $\cot x$ as $\frac{1}{\tan x}$ and using the chain rule leads to a very different answer.

$u = \tan x$ , $du = \sec^2x dx$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx} = \log (\tan x)\sec^2x$$

This yields that $$\log (\tan x)\sec^2x = - \csc^2x$$
$$ \log (\cot x) = \cot^2 x$$
$$e^{\cot^2x} = \cot x$$
What I am wondering is is that if this result has some significance and if there is any intuition behind it?

Comment: I don't really get iy. How is $\frac{dy}{du}= \ln(\tan x))$? @Ziad

Comment: The derivative of $1/x$ is $-1/x^2$. You're mixing it up with the integral.

Comment: Oh my what have i done? I am extremely sorry. I'll let this be a lesson for myself to always check my work then!

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury It's no problem, happens to us all! Please leave the question rather than deleting it. Although, you are free to of course ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Error: Expressing $y=\frac{1}{\tan x}$, $\frac{dy}{du}=-\frac{1}{\tan ^2 x}\frac{du}{dx}$

Comment: And the result we expect, follows.